# Adding bullets to all items from a data variable

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I am using Machform, which is a form creater / maker, for our forms. Unfortunately the developer has no interest anymore in offering support on questions. So I am wondering if someone on stackoverflow can provide some help.

I am using the following piece of code:

```
        if($form_id == 65822){
            if($data['element_id'] == 52){
                if(!empty($data['value'])){
                    $data['value'] = '<p>Example text:</p><ul style="color:#444444 !important;font-size:14px;list-style:square;"><li><a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#444444 !important;" href="#">'.$data['value'].'</a></li></ul>';
                }
            }
        }
```

This works when there is a single item being displayed. The item gets a square (bullet) in front of the item.

However when there are more items, only the first item gets a square (bullet). The rest don't get a bullet.

- First item

  Second item

  Third item

It should, however, be displayed like this:

- First item
- Second item
- Third item
- And so on

So everything which is being displayed should have a square (bullet) in front of it.

Is there an easy fix for this?

The $data['value'] variable is collected from the stuff entered in the form. In this case it's multi-text line / paragraph field.

Comment: It would better to modify the area of code that collects the text that goes into $data['value'] - see my answer

Comment: Is this code in a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would better to modify the area of code that collects the text that goes into $data['value'].
Maybe create a new array variable $data['bullets'] and push each bullet to that individually:

```
$data['bullets'][] = "'<li><a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#444444 !important;" href="#">First item</a></li>";
$data['bullets'][] = "'<li><a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#444444 !important;" href="#">Second item"</a></li>;
$data['bullets'][] = "'<li><a style="text-decoration:none !important;color:#444444 !important;" href="#">Third item</a></li>";

if($form_id == 65822){
            if($data['element_id'] == 52){
                if(!empty($data['value'])){
                    $data['value'] = '<p>Example text:</p><ul style="color:#444444 !important;font-size:14px;list-style:square;">'.implode('',$data['bullets']).'</ul>';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your idea, however that doesn't work. Also I cannot modify other parts of this script because it's encoded. I thought there was an easy solution to this. :( Also the data is already been collected from the form and being displayed by using the $data variable.

Comment: My only other idea is to use a unique identifier to explode $data['value'] into an array of bullets at the place where you are reassigning $data['value']. If you have access to the HTML template you may be able to do this, otherwise I can't think of a way of doing it